# Can't save images from URL. Android

Tags: android, image, url, download, corrupt

first, sorry for my bad english and second, I have a "little" problem. 
I tested a lot of codes from StackOverFlow but i continue with the same problem.

I'm trying to download some images from URL. I have an ExpandableListView and I use a class named Downloadusers to download all information about users.
In this class I get the user's photo URL and I download the images with the following code:

```
 private void downloadFile(String url) {

    String filepath = null;
    try
    {   
      URL nurl = new URL(url);
      HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) nurl.openConnection();
      urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
      urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);                   
      urlConnection.connect();                  
      File SDCardRoot = getExternalFilesDir(null);
      String filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);  
      Log.i("Local filename:",""+filename+"  SDCardRoot: "+SDCardRoot.toString());
      File file = new File(SDCardRoot,filename);
      if(file.createNewFile())
      {
        file.createNewFile();
      }                 
      FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
      InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
      int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
      int downloadedSize = 0;   
      byte[] buffer = new byte[PHOTO_FILE_MAX_SIZE];
      int bufferLength = 0;
      while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) 
      {                 
        fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);                  
        downloadedSize += bufferLength;                 
        Log.i("Progress:","downloadedSize:"+downloadedSize+"totalSize:"+ totalSize) ;
      }             
      fileOutput.close();
      if(downloadedSize==totalSize) filepath=file.getPath();    
    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException e) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      filepath=null;
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i("filepath:"," "+filepath);
}
```

I have also verified that the URLs are correct and I have loaded in the browser. 
With Log.i("filepath:"," "+filepath); I can see that filepath is correct, so I think that images are downloaded correctly but no, image files are corrupt files, so when I go to load the images into my ImageView I have a NullPointException because bMap readed is null due to corrupt images.

I have all permissions: Internet, Write and read external storage and phone state.

I tried too download images with AsyncTask, but I have the same problem.

Someone know what can be my problem? 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you check DDMS? Maybe image couldn't be downloaded successfully. When your virtual device is running, go to DDMS perspective->File explorer->{your path to store image} and check that whether the image is downloaded or not

Comment: Im testing the app on my phone not on an emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using library [nostra13 "universal-image-loader-1.9.2.jar"](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). My code is now:

```
    // If the user photo exists and is public, download and show it. 
    if (Utils.connectionAvailable(activity)
            && (photoFileName != null) && !photoFileName.equals("")
            && !photoFileName.equals(Constants.NULL_VALUE)) {

        // Create options. Setting caché = true (default = false)
        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                            .cacheInMemory(true)
                            .build();

         // Create global configuration and initialize ImageLoader 
         // with this configuration
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration
                                 .Builder(activity.getApplicationContext()) 
                                 .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
                                 .build();

        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

        // Load image, decode it to Bitmap and display Bitmap in ImageView 
        // (or any other view 
        // which implements ImageAware interface)
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(photoFileName, image);
   }
```

With that code I can load the image on caché and show in my imageview without problems.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is my download method. You will download image into SDCARD. You can check whether image is downloaded or not by going DDMS Perspective.

```
public void download(String Url) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL (Url);
    InputStream input = url.openStream();
    try {
        File storagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());

        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream (new File(storagePath, 'myImage.jpg'));
        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        } finally {
            output.close();
        }
    } finally {
        input.close();
    }
  }
```

This snippet is for showing downloaded image in ImageView.

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment
.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "myImage.jpg");
image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: With this method I have 2 problems. 1) The files are showing in the gallery and are privates photos (that's why i do File SDCardRoot = getExternalFilesDir(null); String filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); ) and 2)Files donwloaded are corrupts too.

Comment: For the first issue, you are right. If they are private, then it is better to use getExternalFilesDir(). But if you don't say what LogCat says, it is almost impossible what is wrong about downloading. Because this method works well for me.

Comment: LogCat doesnt say nothing, doesn't show any error. Simply when write the file, write a corrupt file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I was able to solve it by setting

```
urlConnection.setDoOutput(false);
```

and it worked, but I don't know why.